# Cassandra - Remove node from Cluster - Decommission will not work due to disk is FULL

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have 6 Node Cassandra cluster. Then created one more Cluster with 6 nodes and added as a new data center. Now new data center has complete data and I ran `alter keyspace` to remove the old data center.

Everything was fine. Now I want decommission the entire data center. But this old datacenter does't have enough disk space on all of the nodes. 2 nodes are already full.

I ran decommission command on node 4, it returns `No Space Left on the device`. Anyhow this Datacenter is useless now. How can I remove all the nodes.

Comment: Some detailed error message: https://www.reddit.com/r/cassandra/comments/c9d53w/nodetool_decomission_not_able_to_remove_the_node/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do how it's described in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html)?

1. Shutdown the nodes
2. Remove them with [nodetool removenode](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsRemoveNode.html) (use [nodetool assasinate](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsAssassinate.html) as a last resort)

Right now, with your problem just follow these steps...